# How to restart the program all over again (without name) until exit

Tags: loops

I'm just a week into programming. I've spent half the day fixing the loop, but can't seem to get my head around it. When the while condition ends, you have won and it goes to the prints. But afterwards it should start over again if you want to.

Python does not seem to have a goto function.

```
import random
counter = 0
guess = -1

name = input("Hi! Whats your name?\n")
print("")
print ("Hi ", name,"! Shall we play a game?",sep="")

waarde = input ('To which number do you want to guess? ')
waarde = int(waarde)
secretNumber = random.randrange(1,waarde+1)

guess = int(input(f"Oké. Raad het getal tussen 1 en {waarde}: "))
counter +=1

while guess != secretNumber:

    counter +=1

    if (guess > secretNumber):
        print("Fout! Het getal is kleiner!",sep="")
        print("")
        guess = int(input("Raad opnieuw! "))

    else:
        print("Niet goed! Het getal ligt hoger!",sep="")
        print("")
        guess = int(input("Raad opnieuw! "))

print("")
if (counter != 1):

    print("Proficiat ", naam,"!! Het was inderdaad ",guess, "! Je hebt het geraden in ", counter, " beurten!!",sep="")

else:
    print("Proficiat ", naam,"!! Het was inderdaad ",guess, "! Je hebt het geraden in ", counter, " beurt!!",sep="")
```

Comment: You can put loops inside of loops!

Comment: Does this need a Python tag?

Comment: @Wyck Seems like a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking you probably want something structured like:

```py
# Introductory code "hi"

# Game configuration code (set guessing range, if common)

playing = True
while playing:
    # Gameplay code, probably starting from
    secretNumber = random.randrange(1,waarde+1)

    guess = int(input(f"Oké. Raad het getal tussen 1 en {waarde}: "))
    counter = 1 # restart counter per game
    while guess != secretNumber:
        counter += 1
        # higher/lower etc.

    # game result

    # Check to play again
    again = input('Play again y/n: ').lower()
    playing = (again[0] == 'y')

# Now out of the "playing" loop
# Exit code; could add game summaries, "bye"
```